# NOSQL Performance and scalability

Tags: java, sql, nosql

I am came across this article and found out overall the performance for NOSQL still slower than conventional SQL as per URL below.
http://tiborsimko.org/postgresql-mongodb-json-select-speed.html

I understand that NOSQL has capability to scale horizontally and if i add more nodes or VM then could it solve the performance issue base on the URL above? If yes, then how.

Hope can get some answer.

Comment: You might get performance improvements with sharding: https://de.slideshare.net/mongodb/how-queries-work-with-sharding

Comment: assuming i am setting up 4 db instances for the 4 different groups of years using sharding for mongo db. It shall be based on the example on URL below
http://tiborsimko.org/postgresql-mongodb-json-select-speed.html

i)  1980 to 1990 
ii) 1990 to 2000
iii) 2000 to 2010 
iv) 2010 to 2020

Comment: Continue from comment above cause "Add Comment" restricted the length.. It should have significant improvement of performance if query any one of the range above say 1980 to 1990 but if i query from 1980 to 2020 then i have 2 issues here.

i) I cannot join DB from 1980 to 2000?
ii) I have to query all 4 instances or 4 times then consolidate the resultset yet it will impact a lot of the performance. 

Any workaround for it? Or it's the drawback of using NOSQL?

Comment: Sharding would do this for you (i.e. query 4 instances and merge the results). Yes, this will impact the performance as you have distribute queries/join/IO overhead. This still *might* make sense. Especially for certain type of queries where you don't query large ranges.

No, this is not a drawback of NOSQL it is the drawback of horizontal scaling.